# How do I delete an event FullCalendar by posting to flask via ajax and updating SQLAlchemy database?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, fullcalendar, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm completely baffled.

I'm making a seizure tracking app and I'm trying to allow deletion of events in Fullcalendar with a pop-up. When the pop-up is clicked the id of the event should be posted to the @app.route('/delete') and the SQLAlchemy database should be updated, the event removed, and the calendar should be rendered again minus the event.

Here is my terrible attempt at the deletion script.

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                aspectRatio: 2.25,
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                editable: true,
                expandRows: true,
                timeZone: 'Europe/London',
                defaultView: 'listMonth',
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
                },
                weekNumbers: true,
                dayMaxEvents: true,
                events: [
                    {% for event in events %}
                        {
                            id: '{{ event.id }}',
                            title: '{{event.seizure_type}} {{event.note}}',
                            start: '{{event.date}}',
                            textColor: '#000',
                            {% if event.seizure_type == 'Strong' %}
                                backgroundColor: 'red',
                            {% elif event.seizure_type == 'Medium' %}
                                backgroundColor: 'orange',
                            {% else %}
                                backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                            {% endif %}
                        },
                    {% endfor %}
                ],
                eventTimeFormat: {
                    hour: '2-digit',
                    minute: '2-digit',
                    hour12: false
                },
                eventClick: function (event) {
                    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete it?")){
                        var event_id = event.id
                        $.ajax({
                            url:"{{ url_for('delete') }}",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {id: event_id},
                            success:function()
                            {
                                alert("Event Removed")
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            });

            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
```

and the @app.route('/delete')

```
@app.route("/delete", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete(id):
    event_id = request.data.id
    event_to_delete = Seizures.query.get(event_id)
    db.session.delete(event_to_delete)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('show_calendar'))
```

I'm sure this is possible but I'm not versed in JS yet.

Comment: 1. Redirecting from an AJAX request makes no sense - the whole point of AJAX is to stay on the same page. You probably don't need to return anything from the delete route except, at most maybe a true/false to indicate if it successfully deleted the record or not

Comment: 2. Deleting the event in the database won't remove the event from the calendar view on the page at the time.  You need to tell fullCalendar separately to do that - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-remove

Comment: P.S. I've guessed what your issue is, but if you re-read your question you haven't actually explained what specific problem you're experiencing. "Baffled" isn't an error message or problem description! For future questions please remember we can't read your mind, you need to explain the issue clearly - it's not always going to be apparent just from the code :-)

Comment: Sorry this was my first time posting and I'm learning to code as well so it's all a bit confusing. My problem is that I'm trying to update my database to delete a specific event by it's id and then have flask render the calendar again but without the event. And I can't seem to make it work. I'm not getting any errors which makes me think something is really wrong! How do I post the id of the event into the flask @app.route?

Comment: "can't seem to make it work" isn't a useful problem description either though :-). You've described some things which you want to achieve, but not which part of these processes is actually going wrong specifically. Is it failing to delete the item from the database? Or just failing to delete from the calendar display (for which I've already explained the solution)? Or something else? And what debugging have you done? I actually am not familiar with flask (I know the JS and fullCalendar side well, though) but I don't see any obvious issues with what you've done in terms of sending the ID.

Comment: You can a) use your browser's Network tool to verify that the correct ID is being sent in the AJAX request to the delete route (and whether the request actually succeeds), and b) use some sort of logging or debugging tool (I'm not familiar with what tools are available for python/flask) to check what value the ID field has when it arrives in your delete function, and whether any errors occur during the deletion function, including database errors. Obviously you can also check your database table directly to see if the data has been changed or not as a result of running the function.

Comment: Actually though I did just notice something in the fullCalendar side which might be an issue...what version of fullCalendar are you using? In v4 and above, `event.id` will not be the right thing to use in the `eventClick` callback to get the ID. As per the documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick, the arugment to the eventClick function is an info object, of which the event itself is just one sub-section, so `id` is not at the top level of the object. Therefore if you write `eventClick: function (info) { ... var event_id = info.event.id` that should get you the ID correctly.

Comment: I'm learning a lot already! Thank you :) The event is failing to be deleted from the database and I'm not being redirected to the calendar from the @app.route('/delete'). Having checked Chrome's Network console (incredibly helpful, thanks for pointing this out) nothing is being sent.

Comment: I'm using the latest version as per the documentation. Adding info is differently the right step I think, but it still didn't work. It's not being posted to the @app.route.

Comment: `I'm not being redirected to the calendar from the @app.route('/delete')` ...I already explained why that's not a logical thing to expect, see above

Comment: `It's not being posted to the @app.route`...can you be more specific? Do you see the AJAX request launch in the network tool of the browser? You need to watch it in real-time and you should see a request to the delete URL appear after you press OK in the confirm box. Does it appear or not? If so, what response code does it return?

Comment: After chatting to another friend I realised that I was not loading ajax as I had the wrong Jquery version in my script. Having got the correct one now, I'm able to get the id from info.event.id, but when I click the OK button, I get this error in the Chrome console 'jquery-3.6.0.js:10109 POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/delete 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)' and 'event_id = request.data.id
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'id'' in the python console. So at least that's something!

Comment: Ah ok. Yes that is some progress, I can't really help you much with the python stuff as I said, but at least the request is being triggered now

Comment: Seriously, thank you for your help. You've taught me a lot in this short conversation!

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out not to be with the Javascript but with the `flask` `@app.route`. While before I was using `request.data.id` to try to get the data, I should have been using `request.form['id']`. The event is now being deleted from `FullCalendar` and is being deleted from the database.

**Solution:**

```
@app.route("/delete", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete():
    event_id = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        event_id = request.form['id']
        event_to_delete = Seizures.query.get(event_id)
        db.session.delete(event_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('show_calendar'))
```